# after finishing the project, how to make the source code uneditable in C#

Tags: c#

I am programming in C# since half a year. I have made a database project. What I want to do is, now that my project is finished, I want that no one should be able to edit any of the code of my C# project. How can I make my C# project uneditable?

Comment: Just release your project without the source (i.e., compile it and distribute the assembly). If users want to get sneaky and mess with the code, they'll have to decompile it and make changes to that. You can't really stop people from doing this, but it will leave your original code intact as _you_ have that.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you don't need to fix any bugs. Good for you :)

Answer (score 5):

You can hide give out DLLs of the compiled code to others, which they could then use without being able to see / edit the source code.

You can't make code permanently read only / I can't think of a reason why you'd want to (since if you had a bug you'd need to edit this code). However if you put your code into source control (e.g. TFS (free for small teams at http://tfs.visualstudio.com)) you can have a copy of your code with a full change log, so even if someone changed it, you could pull back a version as of today which didn't include their changes.

Alternatively you can use file permissions to stop others from editting the code, or make the files read only if you're worried about accidentally updating the code - but you'd still be able to edit it by amending those permissions / removing the read only flag at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated you cannot really make your code readonly. What you can do is [sign your assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx). Other people will still be able to read and change your code. But as long as you keep your private key private, they will not be able to create the same signed assembly.

This does require that all the assemblies you reference are signed as well and that you store your private key in a safe place. If someone else gets your key, he or she will be able to recreate your assemblies, if you loose your key you will not be able to recreate them.